# Payload contains files with the same destination path

Tags: c#, uwp, nuget, xamarin.uwp

I have build a UWP application, that until recently has been working. Although recently I have been getting an error while compiling for Release.

```
Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'. Source files: 
C:\Users\Cj\.nuget\packages\runtime.win10-x64-aot.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.0-preview1-26926-04\runtimes\win10-x64-aot\lib\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
C:\Users\Cj\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
```

The exception kind of speaks for itself, except I have no idea what packages are calling the file, or how to solve the issue. I have found answers for different libraries that don't work for my situation. And another that said "Uncheck the Compile with .NET Native tool chain" in the build properties, but then the .appxupload bundle doesn't get generated when building for the store.

These are the packages that are installed (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxpTt.jpg)

[image: NuGet packages]

I have updated all these packages except

- Newtonsoft.Json
- Win2d.uwp

I appreciate any help.
Thanks

EDIT - ADDED INFORMATION

I should also state that there is also a .Net Core DLL referenced by the application.

Comment: Does cleaning the Nuget cache helps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders

Comment: Just tested out this. Unfortunately, still get the issue when doing a build.

Comment: What's your Visual Studio build version? When consulting from the internal channel I got some info about a known issue is addressed in the latest Visual Studio. So can you make sure that you are using the latest Visual Studio first?

Comment: Thanks for continuing to work on this. I always try to keep my Visual Studio up to date. The version I have currently is VS2017 v15.8.8. Here is a link to the "About" window - https://imgur.com/a/Y6NwgOG

Comment: Hmmmmmm. Can you also report this directly to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that I have found the NuGet Package that is causing the exception. It seems to be the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform Package.

When the package is updated to the 6.2.0 preview build, the exception occurs. When downgraded to the latest stable, 6.1.9, the exception no longer occurs/changes.

However, when building for x86 a new exception comes up,

```
ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x86.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\x86\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe @"C:\Users\Cj\Documents\Project\GoMobile\Main Branch\GoMobile\GoMobile\GoMobile.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\GoMobile.rsp"' returned exit code -1073740791
```

I do not know what is causing the new error. The package **does** build when targeting x64.

Comment: can you reach out to the .NET Native team at "dotnetnative" at Microsoft dot com? If this only reproes for x86, it's likely an optimizer issue and can probably be worked around to unblock you (plus we'll want to fix this for the next release).

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe package reference to 4.5.2 also fixes the issue while letting you stay on the latest universalwindowsplatform package.

Comment: Should probably update the GitHub issue with this answer to my last question. That's right, I'm on here too! :P

Answer (score 0):

I see the same error message on upgrading to latest version of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.2.2 running latest VS2017 15.9.1

Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'. Source files: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\runtime.win10-x86-aot.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.2\runtimes\win10-x86-aot\lib\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
C:\Users\JM.nuget\packages\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll

Definitely an issue with latest Universal package.